# How to parametrize rails system test based on fixture objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, automated-tests

In a Rails (5.2) project I want to parametrize a system test (Capybara) based on different objects from a test fixture.
I have:

```
class SomethingWithUsers < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  setup do
    @user1 = users(:test_user1)
    @user2 = users(:test_user2)
  end
  test "some_test" do
    login @user1
    do_stuff
    assert other_stuff
   end
end
```

and I have a users.yml fixture.

So now instead of adding second test for @user2, I want to parametrize the `some_test`

I tried:

```
  [@user1, @user2].each do |user|
    test "some_test" + user.name
      login user
      do_stuff
      assert other_stuff
    end
  end
```

but `user` gets nil. So obviously I don't have access to these vars in this way.

```
[users(:test_user1), users(:test_user2)].each do |user|
```

is also not working. So I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
  [:test_user1, :test_user2].each do |u|
    test "some_test" + u.to_s
      user = users(u)
      login user
      do_stuff
      assert other_stuff
    end
  end
```

But I don't find this nice. So other solutions are still welcome.